# Retag Request: [.net][httpclient] to [dotnet-httpclient]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I just edited a question to add the [httpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/httpclient) tag, but noticed the "DO NOT USE" notation in the wiki excerpt. On examination, I found there were about 2,000 questions with the [httpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/httpclient) tag, but only 38 with both [httpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/httpclient) and [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net).

What's the best way to get [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net+httpclient) retagged as [dotnet-httpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dotnet-httpclient)? Should we just start doing that manually?

Comment: I find the alternative confusing. Why can't we tag [tag:.net-httpclient] just like [.net-4.0]? Seems more logical...

Comment: That would be fine with me, but there's already a [dotnet-httpclient].

Comment: If we need to retag I rather retag to the correct tag.  The only reasonable [dotnet] prefix is for [dotnetnuke]. I would say that if we need  to tag a class from the framework it is tagged [.net-NameofClass]. Let's see if there are other opnions....

Comment: @rene: if you look on the tags page, you'll see there are many other tags that start with "dotnet".

Comment: But those are all non microsoft supplied libs/solutions. My idea was to keep the 'official supported' stuff with a start tag that we all know/familiar with. ...